# Realm NSDate is not read correctly

Tags: date, swift3, realm, realm-browser

My situation is as follows: I get a ticket info from an API Call, and I can see in my Realm Browser, that the dates of when I activated the ticket and when it expires are saved correctly in the database in UTC.

In the Database, using Realm Browser, I can see that startTime is Apr 25, 2017, 1:45:30 PM and endTime is Apr 26, 2017, 6:45:30 AM. (My local time was 9:45:30 AM at the time of activating my ticket - so this is correctly setup on servers end)

However, when I access that date later on in code and retrieve it from database it gives me a date with an offset!!! (And no, it's not a date in local timezone - it should've been a date saved in UTC).

Here's some code I use to get the info from database and display it:

```
func getTickets() -> [Ticket] {
        let tickets = userInfo?.tickets.filter("state == %@", "activated").map({ (dbTicket) -> Ticket in
            var startTime: Date? = nil
            var endTime: Date? = nil
            if let start = dbTicket.startTime, let end = dbTicket.endTime {
                print("START ", dbTicket.startTime,
                    "\nNOW ", NSDate(),
                    "\nEND ", dbTicket.endTime)
                startTime = start as Date
                endTime = end as Date
            }
            print("START ", dbTicket.startTime,
                  "\nNOW ", Date(),
                  "\nEND ", dbTicket.endTime)
            return Ticket(id: dbTicket.id, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)
        }) ?? []
        return tickets
    }
```

And here's what gets printed in the console:

```
START  Optional(2017-04-25 17:45:30 +0000) 
NOW  2017-04-25 13:46:15 +0000 
END  Optional(2017-04-26 10:45:30 +0000)

START  Optional(2017-04-25 17:45:30 +0000) 
NOW  2017-04-25 13:46:15 +0000 
END  Optional(2017-04-26 10:45:30 +0000)
```

Which is incorrect! START should be almost the same as NOW. So why START and END dates are read from Realm database incorrectly ? Especially that I can see then in the Realm Browser and there they are saved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` represents a specific point in time, independent of any time zone. The only time that a time zone is associated with an `NSDate` is when creating a string representation of it (in your case, this happens when `print` ends up calling `-[NSDate description]`). If you want to control which time zone the date is formatted with you can explicitly convert `NSDate` to the string using `NSDateFormatter`, which allow you to control the time zone that's used.